# Bash - get content of file

Tags: linux, bash, file, centos

I need to get content of file in bash but i only need specific words which are ahead of a key word.

The file looks like this:

```
conn NameOfConnection1
    some settings

conn NameOfConnection2
    some settings

conn NameOfConnection3
    some settings
```

I would need a bash script which would output only NameOfConnection1,2,3 on each line.

//EDIT:

Little catch. The file have this:

```
    # It is best to add your IPsec connections as separate files in /etc/ipsec.d/
include /etc/ipsec.d/*.conf
```

And some conns are in seperate folder.

Comment: `grep` seems like the tool to use, have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
grep '^conn' file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Comment: that works thanks, but i forgot little catch i edited the question. Guess maybe do loop for .conf extension files in that folder?

Comment: `grep` can handle several files, no need for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` can print/extract the desired output.

```
awk '$1 == "conn" {print $2}' file.txt
```

the above code basically means, If field/column `$1` is `conn` then print the second `$2` field/column.